# In step up transformer which side have high inductance?

Tags: transformer

I plan to use 1:10 center tap step up transformer, in my circuit design. But I have one question, which side have high inductance in step up transformer? (Primary or secondary) Give me some hint of inductance of transformers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the inductance of a winding varies as the number of turns squared, the high voltage side will have higher inductance. With a 1:10 ratio, the high voltage side will have 100x the inductance of the low voltage side.

Do be aware that inductance in power transformers is quite poorly controlled. In most circumstances with a power transformer, it's not the thing you use for the first order design. You do specify an ideal transformer in SPICE with the inductances however.